# Watch an active console window title

Tags: windows, winapi

A have read the [no console hooks allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199747/how-can-i-set-up-a-cbt-hook-on-a-win32-console-window) but it is need to watch title of active console window. It is strange but console window is a window. (without message pump and assigned to another process. I have readed there, do not remember where) But Explorer can see it and show title in the taskbar. What is the mechanize for it or any available solution for watching actual console window title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well more good way to watch top window title than EnumWindows is repetitive use this:

```
HWND hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
if( hwnd ) {
    // foreground window can be NULL in certain circumstances
    GetWindowText( hwnd, buff, length ); 
}
```

each time interval

Answer (score 0):

Console windows are indeed windows like any other. You can enumerate top-level windows with `EnumWindows`. Or you can use any other mechanism to find top-level windows associated with console apps. And you can read their titles with `GetWindowText` just as you can with any other top-level window.

The question that you link to is not related at all to your question. That other question asks why `SetWindowsHookEx` fails from a console app. Well, that's because the console app does not have a message pump. Were the console app to start pumping messages then `SetWindowsHookEx` would work fine. But as I said, that question is simply not relevant to this one.

---

OK, now I see, from your comment, why you are talking about hooks. You want to use a hook to detect window creation and destruction. Use a CBT hook for that. Just make sure the thread it runs in pumps messages.

Note that you don't need to use the main thread to manage the hook. It may be more convenient in a worker thread.

Comment: The link that I have brought is concerning Windows Hooks that is good and effective way to watch top level window. But EnumWindows is not effective way to watch top level window. The reason is cpu loading during repetitive windows enumeration with some frequency. And this result will be not actual on time. But seems to me that it is need to be implemented. It is next reason for "thanx" to microsoft.

Comment: So use a CBT hook then to watch for new windows. It's not as if you mad it 100% clear what your goal was.

Comment: Unfortunately No any CBT hook calls happened for events assigned to console windows. I had try to open (i.e. create) or activate (minimize/maximize etc.) No hooks callback calls happened concerning console windows. So We Can Not Watch active window title for console apps. It is need to do repetitive windows enumeratrions (if it was work) that I currently does not to implement, (I hope it will work)...